# Sharepoint List to ADO.Net data table

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ado.net, moss, wss

Is it possible to convert a share point list (getting it via the web service or object model) and transform it into a ADO.NET data table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or using the [GetDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.getdatatable.aspx) method in the OM:

```
SPWeb oWebsite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList oList = oWebsite.Lists["List_Name"];
SPListItemCollection collListItems = oList.Items;

DataGrid1.DataSource = collListItems.GetDataTable();
DataGrid1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the list items through a SPQuery,

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPSiteDataQuery query=new SPQuery();

//write your own query
// ...

//execute the query 
DataTable tbl = web.GetSiteData(query);
```

Now you have a ADO.NET DataTable to work on.

Comment: For GetSiteData you must pass SPSiteDataQuery object. Fix it.
Moreover, with SPSiteDataQuery it is possible to get list data from multiple lists.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx